# How to flat fields in a subdocument with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection, where each document has an array with snapshots of the document.

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "field1" : "value1",
        "field2" : "value2",
        "field3" : "value3",
        "version" : [
                {
                        "v" : 3,
                        "element" : {
                                "field1" : "value1",
                                "field2" : "value2",
                                "field3" : "value3"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "v" : 1,
                        "element" : {
                                "field1" : "value11",
                                "field2" : "value12",
                                "field3" : "value13"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "field1" : "valueA",
        "field2" : "valueB",
        "field3" : "valueC",
        "version" : [
                {
                        "v" : 2,
                        "element" : {
                                "field1" : "valueA",
                                "field2" : "valueB",
                                "field3" : "valueC"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

With this next operation I retrieve the state of the documents in a specific snapshot:

```
db.test.aggregate( 
    { $unwind: '$version' }, 
    { $match: { 'version.v': { $lte: 3 } }}, 
    { $group: { '_id' : '$_id', 'element' : { $first: '$version.element'}} })
```

And the result is:

```
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "element" : {
                "field1" : "value1",
                "field2" : "value2",
                "field3" : "value3"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "element" : {
                "field1" : "valueA",
                "field2" : "valueB",
                "field3" : "valueC"
        }
}
```

My question is if there is any way to flat the fields in the subdocument 'element' to show in the top-level like this:

```
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "field1" : "value1",
        "field2" : "value2",
        "field3" : "value3"
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "field1" : "valueA",
        "field2" : "valueB",
        "field3" : "valueC"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#add-new-fields-or-reset-existing-fields):

```
> db.test.aggregate(
   { $unwind: '$version' }, 
   { $match: { 'version.v': { $lte: 3 } }},
   { $group: { '_id' : '$_id', 'element' : { $first: '$version.element'}} },
   {$project : { "field1" : "$element.field1",
                 "field2" : "$element.field2",
                 "field3" : "$element.field3" } } ).pretty();
```

That yields your expected output.

However, I'd suggest to consider using a separate collection where each version gets it own document for most use cases that I could think of. Remember that repeatedly growing documents is detrimental to performance, and that the read complexity is relatively high compared to an immediate query...

Comment: I agree that you should not version using this document structure. Take a look at [this blog post](http://askasya.com/post/trackversions) that discusses options for document versioning in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. In my specific case I need always a snapshot of all documents in a collection for an specific version so I thought this approach works well for my purpose, I'm going to read the post talking about options for document versioning.

@mnemosyn Is possible to define all fields in the subdocument with $project in the root without the needed of rewrite one by one? Something like a wildcard or similar: 

$project : { "*" : "$element.*" }

Comment: I don't think it's possible if I interpret this correctly: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267

Comment: @efernandez: You can use special var `"$$REMOVE"` like `{element: "$$REMOVE"}`